# Possible to show that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ by assuming it is true and reducing to $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is possible to show that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ by first assuming that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ is true and reducing to $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}$ ?

For example, my solution was as follow:

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} & = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \\
\\
\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} - \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}\right) & = 0 \\
\\
\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} - \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}\right) \left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} + \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}\right) &= 0 \\
\\
\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)^2 - \frac{(\sqrt{a})^2}{(\sqrt{b})^2} &= 0\\ \\
\frac{a}{b}- \frac{a}{b} &= 0. \\
\end{align}
$$

When Lang simply say $\frac{(\sqrt{a})^2}{(\sqrt{b})^2} = \frac{a}{b}$ and $\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)^2 = \frac{a}{b}$ so it's equal.

Thank you.

Comment: And then you prove that $1=2$ because $(1-2)\cdot(2-2) = 0$ is true.

Comment: But seriously: You cannot prove something by assuming that it is true. Also writing a list of equations does not mean anything. You need implications ($\implies$) or equivalents ($\iff$) .

Comment: @MartinR Yeah I should have taken a simple example, but it seems so correct... Anyway, thank you for your answer I get it now.

Comment: You have a list of equations, and probably you have in mind that each equation implies the next. But you want to show that the last equation implies the first, so you would want to show that these implications are in fact equivalences. Except for one, they all are equivalences, and the one exceptional case is not difficult to handle.

Comment: Note:
$$\sqrt{a} = |a|$$

Comment: @Mostafa did you mean $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ ?

Comment: @Servaes So, if I enumerate my equations $(a), (b), (c), (d), (e)$ and show $(a) \Rightarrow  (b) \Rightarrow (c) \Rightarrow (d) \Rightarrow (e)$ it would have been correct ?

Comment: To the Op: in your attempted solution you already use $(\sqrt{a}/\sqrt{b})^2=a/b=(\sqrt{a/b})^2$. That is, your attempted solution already contains Lang's proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step-by-step analysis .

You need to prove that $\thinspace \sqrt {\dfrac ab}=\dfrac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}\thinspace $, where $a≥0\wedge b>0$ . Therefore, when writing this particular proof, we need to use only *equivalent* steps, not implicative steps .

> For example, my solution was as follow:
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} & = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \tag {1}\\
> (\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} - \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}) & = 0 \tag {2}\\
> (\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} - \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}) (\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} + \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}) &= 0 \tag {3}\\
> (\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}})^2 - \frac{\sqrt{a}^2}{\sqrt{b}^2} &= 0\tag {4} \\
> \frac{a}{b}- \frac{a}{b} &= 0. \tag {5}\\
> \end{align}
> $$

1. $(1)\iff (2)$ .
2. $(2)\iff (3)$ .

Here, I think we need to justify the step $(2)\iff (3)$ . If $a=0$, then the equivalence is correct. Let $a,b>0$, so if $a,b>0$, then $\sqrt{\dfrac ab}+\dfrac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$ is *always* nonzero  .
Therefore, we conclude that, indeed, $(2)\iff (3)$ .

Finally,

3. $(3)\iff (4)$ .
4. $(4)\iff (5)$ .

Since $\dfrac ab=\dfrac ab$ is always true and $(1)\iff (5)$ . Therefore, your proof seems valid to me, if we use equivalent steps .

Comment: It's worth noting that $(4)\iff(5)$ already contains the statement. The Op made it needlessly complicated. Observing that $\sqrt{a}/\sqrt{b}$ squares to $a/b$ suffices

Comment: I was working 
with OP's steps.  This is equivalent to show that,  $$\begin{align}&\left(\sqrt {\frac ab}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}\right)^2\\ \iff &\dfrac ab=\dfrac ab\end{align}$$ where $a,b≥0\wedge b>0.$  Indeed, in this case, showing that $A=B\iff A^2=B^2$ is equivalent to show that $A+B$ is always nonzero, except $A=B=0$ .

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is conceptually wrong (even though it could be fixed) and the fallacy you are making is called [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent). I won't explain it here in detail since the link already provides easy to read explanation.

In short, you don't prove a statement $P$ by starting from it and arriving at something else which you know is true, you need to do the opposite, start from something you know is true and arrive at $P$. In your example, you start from the statement $\sqrt{a/b} = \sqrt a/\sqrt b$ and arrive at a true statement $a/b = a/b$, but you need to do the opposite, for example start from the true statement $a/b = a/b$ and arrive at the statement you want to prove.

The only important lines in your work are the last two where you observe that $$\left(\sqrt\frac ab\right)^2 = \frac ab = \frac{\sqrt a^{\,2}}{\sqrt b^{\,2}}.\tag{1}$$
Let me first explain why this is enough to finish the proof and we need to recall definition of the square root of nonnegative real number:

> If $a\geq 0$ we define $\sqrt a$ as *the unique* nonnegative real number such that $\sqrt a^{\,2}=a$.

The important part is *the unique*, meaning the following: if $x,y\geq 0$ and $x^2 = y^2$, then $x = y$.

So, if we look at $(1)$, all we need to observe is that both $\sqrt{a/b}\geq 0$ and $\sqrt a / \sqrt b \geq 0$ to conclude that they must be equal by uniqueness.

Secondly, we can adapt your attempt to make it a valid proof.

\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt\frac ab\right)^2  = \frac{\sqrt a^{\,2}}{\sqrt b^{\,2}} &\implies \left(\sqrt\frac ab\right)^2 - \frac{\sqrt a^{\,2}}{\sqrt b^{\,2}} = 0\\
&\implies \left( \sqrt\frac ab - \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b} \right) \left( \sqrt\frac ab + \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b} \right) = 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}

At this point we want to divide the equation by $\sqrt\frac ab + \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$, but we can only do that if it's not $0$, which will be true when $a \neq 0$. Thus, when $a\neq 0$, we divide $(2)$ by $\sqrt\frac ab + \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$ to get $$\sqrt\frac ab - \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b} = 0\implies \sqrt\frac ab = \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$$ and we are done and if $a = 0$, then obviously $$ \sqrt\frac ab = 0 = \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}.$$

Comment: IMHO, I belive that OP's intension was something  different . The OP actually wanted to say that, "If $ \thinspace \sqrt {\dfrac ab}=\dfrac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}\thinspace$  "follows" (not assuming that is true) $\dfrac ab=\dfrac ab$ , then does this imply the original statement is true ? (based on OP's steps) which is equivalent to the "If...then... " statement .

Comment: @lone student, their first sentence is "It is possible to show that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$
 by first assuming that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$
 is true and reducing to $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}$" to which the answer is "No, because that's a logical fallacy." If they meant something else, they should edit.

Comment: @lonestudent even if you are right, my answer still answers all their questions and even explains why it's enough to observe that these two square to the same number, so ultimately it doesn't matter, I think.

Comment: Ok, thank you it was a great answer, it really became a lot clearer in my head. You made me realise I misunderstood some proof of chapter 1...

Comment: @kiraloup glad I could help :)

Comment: @lonestudent If I rephrase the original to "If $\thinspace \sqrt {\dfrac ab}=\dfrac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}\thinspace$ then $\dfrac ab=\dfrac ab$" would it make my solution correct ?

Comment: @kiraloup Just based on your mathematical steps, your intension was right . But the presentation was something problematic. Let $\sqrt {\dfrac ab}=\dfrac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$ be a Statement $A$ and $\dfrac ab=\dfrac ab$  be a Statement $B$. You already know that $B$ is true, right ? First recall that, we are working over $a≥0$ and $b>0$.  You showed  that, at least if $A$ is true, then $B$ is true, which is correct. But, this doesn't imply - if $B$ is true, then $A$ is true .  Observe that, $A\implies B$ is correct, bu when $B\implies A$ is incorrect , which could make your proof invalid .